# Error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HtmlAgilityPack' could not be found

Tags: c#, namespaces, html-agility-pack

I am currently working on a Natural Language processing program in which I am accessing Google Translate for my dictionary in order to translate the users input.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
public class GoogleTranslate : MonoBehaviour {
    public static string Translate(string input, string languagePair, Encoding encoding)
    {
        string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text=       {0}&langpair={1}", input, languagePair);
        string result = String.Empty;

        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.E ncoding = encoding;
            result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
        }

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(result);
        return doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//textarea[@name='utrans']").InnerText;
    }
}
```

When I compile this program in Assembly, I am actually using Unity but it compiles with Assembly, I get the return error:

```
Assets/GoogleTranslate.cs(17,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HtmlDocument' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

I began to look up online the proper namespace for HtmlDocument, and read that I should write:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
```

After putting this into my program, I then received the error:

```
Assets/GoogleTranslate.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HtmlAgilityPack' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

I read online that I had to be more specific and use:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument;
```

Now that I put that in, I still continue to receive the error:

```
Assets/GoogleTranslate.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HtmlAgilityPack' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

I would like to know what namespace to use for HtmlDocument. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you import the dll? like, do you remeber adding a dll to your solution?

Comment: Did you add a reference to the HTML Agility Pack DLL?  You should consider using NuGet to download and install HAP in your project!

Comment: Did you add a reference to the correct dll? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack

Comment: No, I did not add the reference, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you downloaded and referenced the HtmlAgilityPack dll? It seems like you're trying to use the (third-party) library without referencing it anywhere in your project/solution.

You can install the library using Nu-Get.

```
Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack
```